# Pythonの "Abcde"[3:] に相当する記述

Tags: c++

Pythonにおいて`"Abcde"[3:] -> "cd"` と書けます。これをC++で簡潔に書くにはどうしたらいいですか？

Comment: 質問の記述ミスでしょうか？ Pythonで`"Abcde"[3:4]`の結果は`"de"`にはならないと思うのですが。それからC++側に何か条件が付いているのでは？ 何も条件が無いのでは想定範囲が広すぎると思われます。

Comment: “Abcde”[3:]でした。終点は含まれませんでしたね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::string_view::substr()`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string_view/basic_string_view/substr.html)が使えます。こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    auto const before = "Abcde"sv;
    auto const after = before.substr(3);

    std::cout << "before: "sv << before << std::endl;
    std::cout << "after: "sv << after << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ご親切にありがとうございます！わかりました。意地悪な回答者が多くて落ち込んでいたのですが、優しく教えていただきありがとうございます。